# Flight leaving country for a layover before coming back. Do I need a multiple entrance visa?

Tags: visas

I'm planning a trip to Tanzania. While in the country I'll take a flight to visit Zanzibar before coming home.

Basically, I will book the following flights with the corresponding layovers :

```
Home country > Netherland (AMS: Amsterdam) > Tanzania (JRO: Moshi)
Tanzania (JRO: Moshi) > Kenya (NBO: Nairobi) > Tanzania (ZNZ: Zanzibar)
Tanzania (ZNZ: Zanzibar) > Kenya (NBO: Nairobi) > Home country
```

During the 2nd flight, I will leave Tanzania before coming back, even though I will stay in the airport. Does this mean that I need a multiple entrance visa? Or does a single entrance visa work for the whole trip?

Comment: What is your citizenship? Do you actually need a visa?

Comment: Also, there are quite a few non-stop flights from JRO to ZNZ, that would probably make things a lot simpler

Answer (score 3):

If you're leaving Tanzania on an international flight, then you will pass immigration and get a stamp, that's an exit, and your visa (if it's a single entry) will be consumed.

Your arrival back in Tanzania, from Kenya, will be considered an international flight, so you will pass immigration, and then you will need a visa, which will be expired already if your visa is single entry as I just said.

So, you will need a multi-entry visa.

Comment: Even though the flight is sold as Tanzania > Zanzibar and Nairobi is just a layover? Technically I stay in the free zone of the airport

Comment: @Popotica the key here is the way you get out of the country, is it an international departure and passing immigration or not?

Comment: @Popotica what is/are the actual flight number(s)? Flights I see via NBO have two different flight numbers, they're connecting flights, not a single domestic flight.

Comment: @Popotica whether you enter Kenya for immigration purposes is irrelevant.  What matters is that you will leave Tanzania.  Some of the people on the plane will be going to other destinations, so everyone on the plane must be counted as having left.